# Truffle Smart Contract Testing does not reset state

Tags: solidity, truffle, testrpc

I have the following `javascript` test for a simple ERC 20 token. Which on the call `return token.balanceOf.call(accounts[2]);` will fetch some old data and fail from a previous test transaction writting similar, but in another contract() scope on the same contract. Using TestRpc

```
contract('ERC Allowance', function (accounts) {

    it("should be able to lend money and that user spend it", function () {
        var token;

        return Token.deployed().then(function (instance) {
            token= instance;
            return instance.approve(accounts[1], 5555, {from: accounts[0]});
        })
            .then(function (approveTransaction) {
                return chftoken .allowance.call(accounts[0], accounts[1]);
            })
            .then(function (allowance) {
                assert.equal(allowance, 5555, "allowance should be increased");
                return token.transferFrom.call(accounts[0], accounts[2], 55555, {from: accounts[1]});
            })
            .then(function (failedTransaction) {
                return token.balanceOf.call(accounts[2]);
            })
            .then(function (balance) {
                assert.equal(balance.valueOf(), 0, "transfer should not go through");
                return token.transferFrom.call(accounts[0], accounts[9], 10000, {from: accounts[1]});
            })
            .then(function (transactionCompleted) {
                return token.balanceOf.call(accounts[2])
            })
            .then(function (balance) {
                assert.equal(balance, 5555, "the balance should be transferred")
            });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To reset the state, you have to tell the test suite to deploy a new instance of the contract before it starts.

You can tell it to deploy a new contract before each "it" with beforeEach(). Every test will start with an initialized state (and a new contract `.deployed()` address).

```
contract( ...

  var contract;

  beforeEach(function() {
     return Contract.new()
     .then(function(instance) {
        contract = instance;
     });
  });

  it("should ...
```

Hope I didn't flub the syntax. Truffle 3.x style.

Comment: I could not use `.new()` with my upgradeable contract (OpenZeppelin), probably because it's not supposed to as there are more than one contract involved. I had to use the `deployProxy` just like it's done in the migration file. Doc: https://docs.openzeppelin.com/upgrades-plugins/1.x/truffle-upgrades#test-usage

Comment: Right. You would have to adapt the principle by deploying a new Proxy in that case.

Answer (score 0):

Following @rob's answer, you can also use the `async` version which might look quite clean to your appeal:

```
let contract;

beforeEach('should setup the contract instance', async () => {
  contract = await Contract.new();
});
```